# Configuration of permissions in Hive tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to set a set of permissions for the tables under a particular database in hive, which is different from the default permissions. 
The database got created with 750 permission and I changed into 755. I used the below hive parameter, but still the tables are having 750 permission,

hive.warehouse.subdir.inherit.perms=true

I need the tables with 755 permission. I am changing the group of the db, inherited to the tables inside but not the permissions.

Comment: Please add details about the distribution and version of hadoop and hive?

Comment: Hive - 0.14.0 , Hadoop - 2.6.0 and Distribution - Pivotal